# NodeJS Debugging Error: No such module: http_parser

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I was debugging my nodejs app in vs-code without errors, but suddenly it did begin to give this error:

```
Error: No such module: http_parser
at internalBinding (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:104:17)
at _http_client.js:27:24
at NativeModule.compile (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:363:7)
at NativeModule.require (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:174:18)
at http.js:25:27
at NativeModule.compile (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:363:7)
at Function.NativeModule.require (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:174:18)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:517:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Actually the app works successfully, for example, `express-js` http functions work as expected, but i am unable to do debugging.

- I have already installed that package, named as `http-parser`

**Edit:** Node Version: v10.14.2, there is no extensions installed, just the vs-code built-in debugging runtime. After i have inspected more, the execution was coming to the *loader.js* and was terminating afterwards.

**Edit2:** Renaming the project folder fixed the issue but why? Could anybody explain this?

Comment: Are you using `node-inspector` for debugging?

Comment: No, i'm not using that package. I just start debugging session from the top menu bar of vs-code. Built-in vs-code debug runtime, nothing else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of node.js and vs code are you debugging?

Some Solutions:

1.Try to rename the project folder

2.Disable extensions and see which extension is influencing the debugging

3.You could also disable the check boxes

All Exceptions and Uncaught Exceptions under Debug > Breakpoints,  can debug your application
check if it works

Comment: No extensions installed.After disabling `All Exceptions` checkbox, i realized that, it comes to loader.js to load the modules and then it suddenly stops. But renaming the project magically worked! But why is that so? Could you explain the reason for it?

Comment: it is probably an error inside `internal/bootstrap/loaders.js` and since all exceptions are caught, it was stopping there

Comment: I can't remember it has been a time since that error, you may be right. Looks like it was related to loaders.js  or it was related to a 3rd party lib named circular json, can't be sure

Comment: Renaming project folder worked for me. may be issue is related to vs code cache or npm cache.

Comment: Thx a lot the 3 fixed it for me. It is amazing we ignore exceptions and the testing still works :D

Answer (score 4):

Go to the debugger tab, go the Breakpoints section, and disable "All Exceptions" and "Uncaught Exceptions"

Answer (score 1):

Deleting .vscode folder in working directory will help but if your debugging points are not getting enabled then try updating vscode. This happened with me when I was using latest nodejs version but a moderately old version of vscode.